# how to make visible assets folder from another app?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have help html fils in assets folder, but they are tied by links to complicated for a WebView; Since a site with an implicit intent it's better but depends of quality connection. I would to read these files  locally with an implicit intent and how can make visible assets folder from a browser and give it a true URL with that ?

Comment: I want to say "too complicated"

Comment: please describe your issue properly

Comment: one way is to use a Webview. HTML file in assets folder is seen, displayed but not hyperlinks, which can even go to crash.    Another way is to send an implicit intent to have a browser, but a browser don't see assets folder which is visible only in private mode. How to access to assets folder from outside, to get a browser available ? There is a way for that ?